# Live Wallpaper reselection increases memory usage. How to stop this?

Tags: android, memory, live, memory-leaks, wallpaper

I just realized that applying a live wallpaper once and then going back to live wallpaper selection, selecting the same wallpaper menu, changing its setting and then setting it as the wallpaper again increases the memory usage of the particular live wallpaper's process. The more we set it repeatedly,the more memory is used.

I tried releasing all resources and yet the same thing is happening. The cube live wallpaper sample has the same problem, as does many others. Since mine uses gif images(using `movie.decodeStream()`), the memory increase is much larger.

I guess its a problem with no cleaning the resources by the wallpaper service. Please advce if this can be done manually. I have tried : `inputStream.close()`, `handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)`, unregistered the sensors etc.

Been working on a simple wallpaper for 3 days day n night now. When everything gets fixed, it starts drinking memory. Any help would be highly appreciated.