# Android memory use doubles when setting live wallpaper

Tags: android

Situation:

During a live wallpaper preview, the user selects "Set wallpaper".

Then, this appears to be the chronological order of events:

Actual wallpaper process: onCreate()

Preview wallpaper process: onDestroy()

Both those processes appear as one name(or are the same process?) while watching DDMS.

The consequence being, if you are using a lot of heap (~more than half), the actual wallpaper crashes on an out of memory error, since freeing of memory is done in onDestroy() (too late) in the preview wallpaper process.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Found another similar link(but no response):

[Live Wallpaper reselection increases memory usage. How to stop this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707128/live-wallpaper-reselection-increases-memory-usage-how-to-stop-this)

Thanks,
Ken